# Modal not closing in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can normally open my modal. However, when I try to close it, I have to click on the back button many times so the modal closes. Does this have to do with how Modal works?

```
import Modal from "react-native-modals";
```

Here is how I open the modal

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    this.setState(
      {
        visible: true,
        latitude: data[1],
        longitude: data[2]
      },
      () => {
        console.log(
          "here should be the coords I want",
          this.state.latitude,
          this.state.longitude
        );
      }
    );
  }}
>
  <Text>Open Modal</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

And here is how I close it

```
<Modal visible={this.state.visible}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          visible: false
        },
        () => {
          console.log("visible should be falsey now", this.state.visible);
        }
      );
    }}
  >
    <AntDesign style={styles.back} name="back" size={50} color="pink" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
  ;
</Modal>;
```

Comment: so how do you wnat to close the modal? on backbutton or some other way?

Comment: @GauravRoy I want to close it with the back button

Comment: whuch modal are you using? react-native-modal?

Comment: yes - import Modal from "react-native-modals";

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using ant design library right?. You can do it like this.

```
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { visible: false };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  };

  handleOk = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  handleCancel = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          Open Modal
        </Button>
        <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was a problem with TouchableOpacity. I was importing it from "react-native-gesture-handler". After changing it to

import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

fixed the issue.